# Obtener valor de botón presionado en ventana modal HTML

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Tengo dos botones en una tabla los cuales abren una ventana modal, si quiero pasar algún valor que me indique qué botón se ha presionado a la ventana modal, ¿cómo lo obtengo?

Mis botones son de tipo `button`:

```
<a href="#" id="link1" data-id="@row.id" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalS">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="si">Si&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>
</a>
<a href="#" id="link2" data-id="@row.id" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalSi">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="no">No</button>
</a>
```

y los coloco dentro de un elemento  para que me abra mi ventana modal

```
<!--modal-->
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="modalSi" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!-- formulario modal -->
                <!-- inicia panel -->
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4>Reporte</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></i>Seleccione una opción</div>
                        <form id="envia" name="envia" method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal">
                            <input type="hidden" name="hddCliente" id="hddCliente" />

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="lblAplicar" class="control-label col-sm-2">Aplicar</label>
                                <div class="input-group date col-sm-10">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span>
                                    </span>
                                    <select name="tipo" size="1" id="tipo" class="form-control">
                                        <option value="">--Seleccionar--</option>
                                        <option value="1">Buzón</option>
                                        <option value="2">Fuera de servicio / número ha cambiado</option>
                                        <option value="3">No contesta</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-sm-2"></label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <!--<input type="button" name="Submit" value="Buscar" id="btn-enviar" class="btn btn-success" />-->
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Guardar</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></i>Resumen del registro</div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="lblfechaSolicitudi" class="control-label col-sm-2">Nombre</label>
                                <div class='input-group date col-sm-10' id='datetimepickerfi'>
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                                    </span>
                                    <input type='text' id="txtNombre" name="txtNombre" class="form-control" disabled />

                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="lblfechaSlicitudf" class="control-label col-sm-2">Telefono</label>
                                <div class='input-group date col-sm-10' id='datetimepickerff'>
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span>
                                    </span>
                                    <input type='text' id="txtTelefono" name="txtTelefono" class="form-control" disabled />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="lblfechaSlicitudf" class="control-label col-sm-2">Fecha Activación</label>
                                <div class='input-group date col-sm-10' id='fecha'>
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                    </span>
                                    <input type='text' id="txtFechaa" name="txtFechaa" class="form-control" disabled />
                                </div>
                            </div>


                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- termina panel -->
                <!--fin formulario modal-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--modal-->
```

JS

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#modalSi').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
                /* aqui obtengo el valor */
                var link = $(event.relatedTarget);
                var btn = $(link).find('button').val();
                console.log($(e.currentTarget).find('#hddBoton').val(btn));
                $(e.currentTarget).find('#hddBoton').val(btn)
                // termina obtener valor

                var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data().id;
                hola.children().each(function () {

                    var celdas = hola.children();
                    console.log($(celdas[4]).text());
                    $(e.currentTarget).find('#txtNombre').val($(celdas[0]).text());
                    $(e.currentTarget).find('#txtTelefono').val($(celdas[1]).text());
                    $(e.currentTarget).find('#txtFechaa').val($(celdas[3]).text());
                });

            });
   });
```

seleccione el botón no y esto son los valores que me obtiene
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, creo que deberías incluir la parte de tu HTML en la cual se encuentra el modal al que estás haciendo referencia: `#modalS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el modal es de Bootstrap se puede obtener el elemento presionado con

`var link= $(event.relatedTarget);`

En este caso sería el elemento **a**

Si se desea el botón que contiene puede obtenerse con

```
$(link).find('button');
```

A partir de ahí es cuestión de buscar una forma de identificarlos. En este caso puede hacerlo con el atributo value de la siguiente forma

```
var btn= $(link).find('button').val();
//En base a su código, haciendo esto btn contendría 'si' o 'no'
```

[Aquí puede ver la documentación relacionada](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target)

Comment: No he podido dejar un comentario por falta de reputación pero a tu pregunta le falta un poco de detalle. La única razón por la cual entendí es porque recuerdo tu pregunta anterior, relacionada también con modales.

Comment: me obtiene los dos valores de los botones

Comment: ¿Cómo los dos valores? Dentro de cada link hay un único valor. ¿Podrías editar y agregar la sección donde tratás de obtener el valor?

Comment: ya coloque como estoy recuperando el valor

Comment: ¿Qué escribe console.log(btn)?

Comment: obtiene los valores si y no, puse la pantalla que muestra lo que imprime console arriba @ibooio

Comment: Acabo de ver un error: usaste event.relatedTarget y deberías usar e.relatedTarget. Cuando yo puse la respuesta no sabia el nombre de tu variable

Comment: de nuevo gracias man

Comment: hola una pregunta como puedo recuperar el valor de un textbox(de una ventana modal) en otra ventana modal nueva?